# Get the sequence no of the message processing in Spark Streaming

Tags: java, apache-spark, counter, spark-structured-streaming

I am using Spark Structured streaming for processing the messages and I am using Java8. I am reading the message from the kafka and writing the message to the file and save the file in HDFS.

I got a requirement like I need to write a sequence number along with the message to file.

For example, if I get the first message from `kafka`, the output file content will be "message, 1" , for second message its "message,2" etc.. kind of count.

if the message count reaches some threshold let say "message, 999999", then I need to reset the sequence from 1 again from the next message I received.

if the spark streaming job is restarted, it should continue with the sequence where it left.  So I need to save this number in `HDFS` kind of `checkPointLocation`.

What is the best approach I can use to implement this sequence. Can I use Accumulator to do that? or is there any other better to approach to implement during the distributed processing ?  or is it not possible in distributed processing?

Answer (score 0):

It wont be that hard.You can read each message using a map function and keep on adding the count to the messages.The count can be maintained with in your code logic.

Comment: It wont help during the parallel processing and also I need to recover the count if my job fails.

Comment: You could reliably use an accummulator inside a foreach loop to achieve this.

Comment: I tried.. but its resetting whnever i restart the spark job.. i want the accumulator to start where it stoppee..